# Distance correlation versus mutual information

Tags: correlation, mutual-information, distance-covariance

I've worked with the mutual information for some time. But I found a very recent measure in the "correlation world" that can also be used to measure distribution independence, the so called "distance correlation" ( also termed Brownian correlation): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_covariance. I checked the papers where this measure is introduced, but without finding any allusion to the mutual information.

So, my questions are:

- Do they solve exactly the same problem? If not, how the problems are different?
- And if the previous question can be answered on the positive, what are the advantages of using one or the other?

Comment: Try to write down explicitly 'distance correlation' and 'mutual information' for a simple example. In the second case you will get logarithms, while in the first - not.

Comment: @PiotrMigdal Yes, I'm aware of that difference. Could you please explain why is it important? Please, take into account that I'm not a statistician...

Comment: For ma a standard tool measuring mutual dependence of probability distributions is the mutual information. It has a lot of nice properties and its interpretation is straightforward. However, there may be specific problems where distance correlation is preferred (but I have never used it in my life). So what is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: This comment is a few years late but Columbia University's Statistics Dept made the academic year 2013-2014 a year of focus on measures of dependence. In April-May 2014, a workshop was held that brought together the top academics doing work in this field including the Reshef Brothers (MIC), Gabor Szekely (distance correlations), Subhadeep Mukhopadhay to name a few. 

Here's a link to the program that includes many pdfs from the presentations.

http://dependence2013.wikischolars.columbia.edu/Nonparametric+measures+of+dependence+workshop

Answer (score 9):

Information / mutual information does not depend on the possible values, it depends only on the probabilities therefore it is less sensitive. Distance correlation is more powerful and simpler to compute. For a comparision see

http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~tibs/reshef/comment.pdf

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! The paper you refer to is about MIC, which is I'm believe is a bit more than MI. I have implemented the distance correlation measure and I don't think it be simpler than the MI for the elemental case of discrete categorical variables. Then again one thing that I have learned is that DCM is well defined and well behaved for continuous variables, but with MI you need to do binning or fancy stuff ala MIC.

Comment: However, DCM seems to need square matrices whose side is the number of samples. In other words, space complexity scales quadratically. Or at least that's my impression, I would like to be in a mistake. MIC does  better, because you can tune it in some sort of compromise between precision and performance.